# My game works perfectly in Eclipse, but doesn't work in texteditor (ubuntu while using terminal). Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am a first year CS student and I had to make a guessing game in java. It works fine in Eclipse, but in ubuntu terminal the program barely works. It only asks me once for a guess of a number and that's it.

After I give my answer it doesn't ask me again like it does in Eclipse.

Does anyone know how to fix? Sorry that it's in dutch.

```
public class Opgave0 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    Random random = new Random();
    int getal = 0;
    System.out.println("Geef een getal tussen 1 en 10, je mag drie keer raden.");
    System.out.println("Eerste keer:");
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    getal = Scanner.nextInt();
    x = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
    if (getal > 10) {
        System.out.println("Het getal is te hoog, kies een getal van 1 tot 10 en probeer het opnieuw.");
    }
    else if (getal < 1) {
        System.out.println("Het getal is te laag, kies een getal van 1 tot 10 en probeer het opnieuw.");
    }
    else {
        if (getal > 0 && getal < 10) {
            if (getal == x) {
                System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
            } 
            else if (getal > x) { 
                System.out.println("te hoog");
                System.out.println("Tweede keer:");
                getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                if (getal == x) {
                    System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                }
                else if (getal > x) {
                    System.out.println("te hoog");
                    System.out.println("Derde keer:");
                    getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                    if (getal == x) {
                        System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                        }
                    else if (getal > x) {
                        System.out.println("te hoog");
                        }
                    else if (getal < x) {
                        System.out.println("te laag");
                        }
                }
                else if (getal < x) {
                    System.out.println("te laag");
                    System.out.println("Derde keer:");
                    getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                    if (getal == x) {
                        System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                        }
                    else if (getal > x) {
                        System.out.println("te hoog");
                        }
                    else if (getal < x) {
                        System.out.println("te laag");
                        }
                }

            }
            else if (getal < x) {
                System.out.println("te laag");
                System.out.println("Tweede keer:");
                getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                if (getal == x) {
                    System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                }
                else if (getal > x) {
                    System.out.println("te hoog");
                    System.out.println("Derde keer:");
                    getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                    if (getal == x) {
                        System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                        }
                    else if (getal > x) {
                        System.out.println("te hoog");
                        }
                    else if (getal < x) {
                        System.out.println("te laag");
                        }
                }
                else if (getal < x) {
                    System.out.println("te laag");
                    System.out.println("Derde keer:");
                    getal = Scanner.nextInt();
                    if (getal == x) {
                        System.out.println(x + " klopt, goed geraden!");
                        }
                    else if (getal > x) {
                        System.out.println("te hoog");
                        }
                    else if (getal < x) {
                        System.out.println("te laag");
                        }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Kies een getal tussen 1 en 10, jouw getal is te hoog/laag");

            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How will it ask again ? There is no loop ..

Comment: is confusing to call your `Scanner` object `Scanner`

Comment: I try your code both eclipse and command line and ask me 3 times before correctly ending even from command line....

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using a loop, so the code you posted will only execute once (as you see from the command line) The only way that it could be asking more than once in eclipse is that you are actually executing several times.

Comment: the code ask 3 times before end...@hu7 said that in command line it ask just once while in eclipse run normally....

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop in your code. So keep your programme up put your all implementation which contains within main method in to a infinite loop.

```
while(true){
   //Your implementation for the game
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your terminal console does not return the correct 'line-return character'. Try in your console-preferences to set the correct character encoding (UTF-8? try it)

Comment: Line return is platform specific, but this is taken care of in System.properties